# Use SQL Server CE with node-webkit

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sql-server-ce, node-webkit

I need to work on an old application written with WPF and MS SQL Server Compact Edition. As a requirement the app is executed from an USB stick (where also all the data is persisted) and the same should apply for the new system.

In the new application I would like to use NoSQL db to store the data ([node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#building-for-node-webkit) or [npm-nosql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nosql)).
 However the records currently stored on the SQL CE database must be migrated to the new db or the same SQL CE database used again (even if I prefer to avoid this option).
 In the latter case, I have seen there is [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) as database connector, but SQL Server CE is not among the supported databases.
The current SQL CE schema is extremely simple, only 4 tables and less than 300 records in total. The application is executed locally by a single user.

Is there a way to export the SQL CE database so that I can import it into the new database? Are there better databases to be used with node-webkit other than the ones aforementioned?

Comment: It sounds like there is a mismatch between what "you would like" and the rquirements for the application. What is wrong with using WPF and SQLCE?

Comment: The old application works well, even if slightly slow. The wish to rewrite it is driven by my personal wish to learn from this project. I would like to use NoSQL, nw, Node.js and AngularJS to make some more experience with those technologies. Isn't it possible to write such an application with node webkit and NoSQL running from USB stick?

Comment: If it is slow, you can make it faster! I am not sure that those JavaScipt technologies were designed for running from a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ for the comments. Actually it is easily possible to run desktop apps even with JS technologies thanks to node-webkit. Here just a couple of links for reference: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js, https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/992.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver you're looking for is:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ce-mssql

However - I'm afraid you'll need to fork a nodejs process from your webkit application, and feature your queries through web API - this will put you at home with Angular.